# Publishing .Net projects to a subdirectory

Tags: asp.net

I have a project (.NET 3.5 C#) that works fine on the local machine and works fine when I publish to the root directory of the server but fails when I publish it to a subdirectory on the server. Is there some sort of setting that I have to change to put it on a subdirectory?

Same thing for both web services and a web site in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set that sub directory to an application in IIS (pretty simple, I promise).  Here is an MSDN article detailing the steps that you need to take for this to work (IIS 6).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha2y9493.aspx